# How do I change the height percentage on a selected image in MS Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, height, shapes

When manually selecting an image in MS Word, there are two "heights". One has dimensions, the other is a percentage. I want to change the percentage. The property for this is not Height, but ScaleHeight. The code I'm providing works for all images. Is there a way to do this for a selected image?

```
Sub aaImage60()

Dim shpIn As InlineShape

For Each shpIn In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
shpIn.ScaleHeight = 60
Next shpIn

End Sub
```

Comment: In the loop, check shpIn.Title and act upon it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have selected the inline image, this will work:

```
With Selection.InlineShapes(1)
    .ScaleHeight = 60
End With
```